# Comando Gulp não funciona

Tags: css, sass, gulp, npm

Olá,

Eu criei um arquivo home.sass

```
@import molecules/mixins

@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap /variables
@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap /mixins
@import ../bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint`
```

Essas linhas eram para importar esse arquivos para minha pasta css mas quando dou o comando gulp, os arquivos não são importados ele lê meu gulpfile e depois não aparece mais nada no terminal e sempre tenho que encerrar o comando dando ctrl + C

```
C:\Users\loja\Desktop\Alacarte>gulp
[15:41:46] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Alacarte\gulpfile.js
[15:41:46] Starting 'sass'...
[15:41:46] Starting 'watch'...
[15:41:47] Finished 'watch' after 210 ms
[15:41:48] Finished 'sass' after 1.92 s
[15:41:48] Starting 'default'...
[15:41:48] Finished 'default' after 22 μs
```

esse é meu gulpfile

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
});
```

Podem me Ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a alguns dados, os seus arquivos de `@import` estão sendo chamados de forma errada, falta a ***extensão** e falta circundar a url com 'aspas' simples.

***Mencionei** que falta a extensão pois não sei como estão nomeados os seus arquivos, caso os seus arquivos estejam nomeados com `_ underline` no ínicio do nome do arquivo **_meu-scss.scss** tudo bem chama-los sem a extensão.

> Forma de importar a url

```
@import '<nome-da-pasta>/<nome-arquivo><.><extensão-do-arquivo>';
```

Mudando seu código para o formato correto ele ficará assim

```
@import 'molecules/mixins.sass';
@import '../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap /variables.sass';
@import '../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap /mixins.sass;'
@import '../bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint.sass`;
```

Já no arquivo `gulpfile.js` você precisa confirmar a url da pasta que pretende monitorar.

```
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass',['sass]);
```

A forma de passar a `url` seria assim inserindo o caminho a partir do `./` do diretório inicial.

```
gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.sass',['sass]);
```